# Attaching OSB sheathing to 2x4 purlins over 12" OC rafters

Tags: roof

I'm building a small (65 sq ft. over-engineered) shed using metal roofing. I've designed it using 2x8 rafters spaced 12" OC, then I plan to put 2x4 purlins on top spaced 16", 7/16" structural sheathing on top of that with an ice/water shield and finally the roof. I designed it this way for two reasons: 1) To give the field screw spacing required by the metal roof and 2) To give a place for a subfascia to be nailed into the purlins.

I have two questions:

1. What would be the appropriate nail size for going through the sheating and purlins in the field - planning to hit the rafters? I'm thinking 1.5" + 7/16" - call it 2" then a 10d ring shank should be sufficient with a 1" penetration into the rafter?
2. I am waivering on the best way to attach the purlins. One way would be 2 nails per connection. The other would be using one headlok 4-1/2" structural fastener at every purlin/rafter intersection. Any recommendations?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using 2x4 purlins **AND** 7/16" structural sheathing, Purlins are usually used in place of sheathing. The sheathing will  allow the required "*field screw spacing required by the metal roof*" or any spacing for that matter. I could be confused but i do not see the reasons for the extreme over engineering.

Comment: @AlaskaMan two main reasons come to mind: a) the assumption the structural sheathing would help with snow load and b) the sheathing/membrane would add a layer of protection against condensation. This is a relatively shallow roof (12/2 pitch) and granted it's not conditioned I just want to make sure what's inside does not get water damage. But I would love to avoid that complication for sure.